# Java - java.lang.NullPointerException (put data into List<>)

Tags: java

I would like to know why I have got this error. Have you got idea and do you know how to fix it?

Error(I get this error in put()):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at nacs.put(nacs.put:36)
at Program.main(Program.java:69)
```

Program: (Main)

```
Nac nacs = new Nac();
nacs.put(new Intsult(1));
nacs.put(new Intsult(2));
```

Class:

```
public class Nac implement IPoraw
{
public List<IAbstrsUlt> abs;
public void put(IAbstrsUlt value)
{
abs.add(value);
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initialize list.

```
private List<IAbstrsUlt> abs = new ArrayList<IAbstrsUlt>();
```

*Note: You should always try to declare your members more restrictive. Default value for Object is null. Refer [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to know default values.*

Comment: "Initialize the list" is the real answer. "Use private not public" is good advice in general, but doesn't have anything to do with the `Exception`. I feel you should separate the two and not present both as part of the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Variable abs is never initialized.

try this

```
public List<IAbstrsUlt> abs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<IAbstrsUlt> abs;
```

**-** In the above statement you have simply **declared** an `List Reference Variable` named `abs` of type `IAbstrsUlt`, and as the `Object Reference Variable` has a **default value** of `null`, so it does in this case too.

**-** You must **initialize** it.

`public List<IAbstrsUlt> abs = new List<IAbstrsUlt>();`